# Inno Setup error- you must be logged in as administrator to run this application

Tags: installation, inno-setup, setuptools

I built a setup.exe file to be installed as administrator as I want it to be stored in Program files(X86) folder, But when I run Setup.exe it shows error- *you must be logged in as administrator to run this application*. **even when I run it as administrator**.
Please Answer how can I fix it.

Comment: Do have the log file enabled? You can call your setup with `MySetup.exe /LOG="logfile.txt"` to get a logfile ... maybe that contains some more details. Also: You could post which settings you are using in your `[Setup]` section (minus the GUID)

Comment: We need [mcve].